# lldb not working with VS Code on Mac - outDebug file

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, lldb

I'm new to VS Code. I got debugging with lldb working--for one day it worked great.
Then it began to malfunction, displaying the arrow several source statements away from the actual execution. I've tried several config changes using online guidance to no avail. I thought that maybe the debug database was messed up so I wanted to try to get it to regenerate, so moved the outDebug file aside. That did not cause it to be rebuilt.
I'm running this launch.json configuration:

```
   {
      "name": "(lldb) Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/rmv_ms",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "lldb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb",
      "preLaunchTask": "clang build active file"
    },
```

and this in tasks.json:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "clang build active file",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-std=c17",
            "-stdlib=libc++",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "group": { "kind":"build", "isDefault":true },
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },`enter code here`
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
    }
]
```

The latest behavior is that when I try to start debug session it displays a menu asking me what to attach to (whatever that means) but I don't even see my program listed.